# How pcregrep force to return first match of regexp

Tags: regex, bash, pcregrep

I have ci-pipelines and there are a lot of `before_scripts` sections. I would like to make a multiline regexp. I export all before script to `my-ci-jobs.txt` with python script.

```
pcregrep -M 'before_script.*\n.*' my-ci-jobs.txt 
"before_script": [
    "yarn install"
"before_script": [
    "yarn install"
"before_script": [
    "yarn install"
"before_script": [
    "yarn install"
"before_script": [
    "yarn install"
"before_script": [
    "yarn install"
"before_script": [
    "yarn install"
"before_script": [
    "yarn install"
"before_script": [
    "yarn install"
"before_script": [
    "yarn install"
"before_script": [
    "yarn install"
```

This works fine, but sometimes, there are more lines in before script, so I would like to make regular that catch everything between before_script and first match of `],`. But when I implement it, it will catch the longest match. This is my command (I will not past here the result, it is the whole file till the last `],`):

```
pcregrep -M 'before_script.*(\n|.)*],' my-ci-jobs.txt
```

How can I make regexp to match first match? Is there a better way how to do a multiline regexp?

Comment: Thank you for replay. This does not work. It returns nothing.

Comment: Does [this](https://regex101.com/r/mmNTu7/4) help?I edited the regex. It'll help if you provide the expected result of the above input. Perhaps you can create a small sample of your file and paste.

Comment: Thats works, thank you. Could you explain the reqexp and Answer my question?

Comment: I think you just need `pcregrep -M 'before_script[^]]*]' file`. If you need the first match only, add `| head -1`

Comment: I needed first match of `before_script` something `],` but basically I need  all  `before_scripts` and then check the diffs. Your first reqular works perfectly as I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost never need `(.|\n)`  in a regular expression, there are better means to match any chars including line break chars.

To match any zero or more chars but `]` you may use `[^]]*` pattern:

```
pcregrep -M 'before_script[^]]*]' file
```

If you need the first match only, add `| head -1`:

```
pcregrep -M 'before_script[^]]*]' file | head -1
```

**Pattern details**

- `before_script` - some literal text
- `[^]]*` - a negated bracket expression that matches any chars but a `]` char, 0 or more times, as many as possible (since `*` is a greedy quantifier) (it matches line break chars, too, because you pass an `-M` option to `pcregrep`)
- `]` - a literal `]` char (no need to escape it because `]` outside a character class is not special).